# Bayesian parameter estimate when you have multivariate errors

Tags: probability, bayesian, model, goodness-of-fit, measurement-error

I have $N$ measurements, $(x_i, \, y_i, \, z_i)$, each comes with standard errors, $(\sigma_{x_i}, \sigma_{y_i}, \sigma_{z_i})$. For context, these are three different astronomical measurements taken at the same point in the sky, for $N$ different points in the sky. The model for these measurements is:

$$ z(x,y) = \alpha\,x + \beta\,y $$

I want to do parameter estimation for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but instead of just the best fit parameters, I want the probability density function. Now, using Bayes' Theorem:

$$ P(\alpha,\beta \ | \ \left\{x_i,\,y_i,\,z_i\right\}_{i=0}^N,\,I) =  \frac{P(\left\{x_i,\,y_i,\,z_i\right\}_{i=0}^N \ | \ \alpha,\,\beta,\,I) \,P(\alpha,\,\beta \ | \ I)}{P(\left\{x_i,\,y_i,\,z_i\right\}_{i=0}^N \ | \ I)}$$

where $I$ contains other information such as prior knowledge of the errors.  I don't quite seem to know how to compute $P(\left\{x_i,\,y_i,\,z_i\right\}_{i=0}^N \ | \ \alpha,\,\beta,\,I)$ when there are errors for all the variables.

If I only had the errors for $z_i$, then I have,

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(\left\{z_i\right\}_{i=0}^N \ | \ \alpha,\,\beta,\,I) &= \prod_{i=1}^{N} P(z_i\ | \ \alpha, \, \beta, \, I) \\ &= \prod_{i=1}^{N} \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma_{z_i}^2}} \exp{\left( - \frac{(z_i - z(x_i, y_i))^2}{2 \sigma_{z_i}^2} \right)} \right]
\end{aligned}
$$

But this is really easy for one-dimensional errors because the independent variables correspond between data and model.

How do I do this while incorporating the three-dimensional errors (where even the independent variables have errors)?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is related to Data Validation and Reconciliation (DVR).
I suggest you look at the paper: Data Validation with Unknown Variance Matrix, Didier Maquin et al. You can either use direct method or indirect methods to estimate variance in multi-dimensional distribution.